# Users to choose how to view images

Tags: 7, media, javascript, views

Is it possible to offer viewers different options on how to view an image?

Currently, it just defaults to a flexslider that I have put as default on my image style.

Looking for instructions on how to achieve this functionality by using views.

I know there is a similar post [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32788/choosing-image-style-during-content-creation) but that is **WHILST** creating the content type - I want the user to choose how to see a set of images after the images have been added to the website!

Answer (score 0):

Use different view modes for your entity (node).  Each view mode (also called a build mode) can have different template (.tpl.php) files.  Use [hook_entity_view_mode_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_mode_alter/7) to decide which view mode to use (based on your user's selection).

You can use the [View Modes module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1577752) to create custom view modes.